# What changes do I need to make to my kotlin project to output libraries and not an executable

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin

I have a solution that contains a few different Kotlin projects. 
1. Spring framework API project
2. Executable tool that does some database work 
3. Client code that serves as a wrapper for the API to be called from other solutions

Right now the Client Code is expecting a main method because I believe it's building as an executable, and I'm not sure why. I wasn't the creator of the project so I don't know what type/settings it was created with.

Are there any changes I can make to the project or perhaps some gradle settings that will output the Client code as a jar of code (instead of libraries) that can then be used in a different solution?

Note: It's important that I don't impact the output types of the Spring api project or the Executable DB tool. Those need to remain the same.

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: please provide more details about your current build scripts:  what are the Gralde plugins applied to each of your projects?